# Kafka rest proxy for windows

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, kafka-rest

Any solution for windows to setup and run the Kafka rest proxy? so i can browse and send the API get/post message via IP/browser?

e.g. at windows browser to get the topics, and use the soapui tool to send GET message to do query? http://IPaddress:8082/topics

I have Kafka server and Zookeer running at windows environment.
Creating topics and viewing topics via cmd is working fine, but when browsing url http://localhost:8082/topics , i got empty server response, i guess it is due to kafka-rest isn't install at windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka-rest is a part of confluent platform. It is supported only on [Linux platforms](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/index.html#production-environments). But you can deploy the docker image of rest-proxy on windows. The image is available [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest).

> docker run -d \   --net=host \   --name=kafka-rest \   -e
>   KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:32181 \   -e
>   KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS=http://localhost:8082 \   -e
>   KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://localhost:8081 \
>   confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.3.0

The link for docker configuration is [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#kafka-rest-proxy-configuration)

Comment: just managed to pull the docker kafka-rest. how do i run it with my current kafka server? i could not find the binaries kafka-rest file at windows. i am running kafka server at windows.

Comment: Edited the answer to add the docker configuration parameters

Comment: not really understand your edited comment, is that a command to run at git bash? docker run -d \ --net=host \ --name=kafka-rest \ -e KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:32181 \ -e KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS=http://localhost:8082 \ -e KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://localhost:8081 \
confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:5.3.0

Comment: This is a command you can run on the shell, of-course edit the value of parameters like KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT to reflect your kafka setup